# Golang method with pointer receiver

Tags: go

I have this example code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IFace interface {
    SetSomeField(newValue string)
    GetSomeField() string
}

type Implementation struct {
    someField string
}

func (i Implementation) GetSomeField() string {
    return i.someField
}

func (i Implementation) SetSomeField(newValue string) {
    i.someField = newValue
}

func Create() IFace {
    obj := Implementation{someField: "Hello"}
    return obj // <= Offending line
}

func main() {
    a := Create()
    a.SetSomeField("World")
    fmt.Println(a.GetSomeField())
}
```

`SetSomeField` does not work as expected because its receiver is not of pointer type.

If I change the method to a pointer receiver, what I would expect to work, it looks like this:

```
func (i *Implementation) SetSomeField(newValue string) { ...
```

Compiling this leads to the following error:

```
prog.go:26: cannot use obj (type Implementation) as type IFace in return argument:
Implementation does not implement IFace (GetSomeField method has pointer receiver)
```

How can I have the `struct` implement the interface **and** the method `SetSomeField` change the value of the actual instance without creating a copy?

Here's a hackable snippet:
https://play.golang.org/p/ghW0mk0IuU

I've already seen this question [In go (golang), how can you cast an interface pointer into a struct pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221854/in-go-golang-how-can-you-cast-an-interface-pointer-into-a-struct-pointer), but I cannot see how it is related to this example.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Your pointer to the struct should implement the Interface. In that way you can modify its fields.

Look at how I modified your code, to make it working as you expect:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type IFace interface {
    SetSomeField(newValue string)
    GetSomeField() string
}

type Implementation struct {
    someField string
}    

func (i *Implementation) GetSomeField() string {
    return i.someField
}

func (i *Implementation) SetSomeField(newValue string) {
    i.someField = newValue
}

func Create() *Implementation {
    return &Implementation{someField: "Hello"}
}

func main() {
    var a IFace
    a = Create()
    a.SetSomeField("World")
    fmt.Println(a.GetSomeField())
}
```

Answer (score 42):

The simple answer is that you won't be able to have the struct implement your interface while having `SetSomeField` work the way you want.

However, a pointer to the struct will implement the interface, so changing your `Create` method to do `return &obj` should get things working.

The underlying problem is that your modified `SetSomeField` method is no longer in the method set of `Implementation`.  While the type `*Implementation` will inherit the non-pointer receiver methods, the reverse is not true.

The reason for this is related to the way interface variables are specified: the only way to access the dynamic value stored in an interface variable is to copy it.  As an example, imagine the following:

```
var impl Implementation
var iface IFace = &impl
```

In this case, a call to `iface.SetSomeField` works because it can copy the pointer to use as the receiver in the method call.  If we directly stored a struct in the interface variable, we'd need to create a pointer to that struct to complete the method call.  Once such a pointer is made, it is possible to access (and potentially modify) the interface variable's dynamic value without copying it.

Comment: thanks james for sharing! I guess this should be the accepted answer as provides a more detailed answer of the internals of interfaces and struct's pointer receiver methods.

Comment: "If we directly stored a struct in the interface variable, we'd need to create a pointer to that struct to complete the method call." - Not true actually. Here is an example:  https://play.golang.org/p/v3Rl3l0MKZ7

Comment: @UdayHiwarale: your example includes no interface variables.  See this error: https://play.golang.org/p/0ABWJlxC_oQ